# KVM/QEMU CPU & RAM performance

Tags: performance, ram, cpu, kvm-virtualization, qemu

What is difference in performance between real CPU cores and vCPU in VM using KVM/QEMU? How much is vCPU slower than bare metal CPU?

And same question for RAM, I know that I can set hugepages, but I do not want, because if I set, I will lost some RAM at host even if VM is no running, so hugepages is not for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a properly setup KVM VM host, one that leaves sufficient RAM and CPU for the host to manage VMs, I've seen 95-98% vCPU compared to native.

However, if the CPUs are overallocated, then performance will suffer. I try to leave 1 CPU just for the hostOS and don't over allocate too many vCPUs to any single VM.  Generally, each VM only gets 1 vCPU assigned unless there is a specific need for 2.  I've never assigned more than 2 vCPUs, but we don't do geospacial DBs here either.

There is a youtube video showing GPU passthru for Windows gaming where 95% of gaming performance including FPS is shown using benchmark tools.  I'm not a gamer, but many people who are interested in raw CPU performance inside a VM are.

Comment: and what about RAM performance? Like latency etc.

Comment: If you don't over-commit RAM, it is a non-issue.  Context switching of the vCPU is probably a bigger issue, IMHO.  OTOH, I don't worry about either CPU nor RAM performance much.  Disk and network I/O is 1,000x more important provided you do not over-commit.